# Remove specific permissions for the s3 bucket owner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I have created a s3 bucket and along with it i added a policy to the bucket saying to deny ListBucket action for a canonical user. Here canonical user is nothing but me. Below is my code..

```py
s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
bucket_policy = {
    'Version': '2012-10-17',
    'Statement': [{
        'Sid': 'AddPerm',
        'Effect': 'Deny',
        'Principal': 
#I am denying ListBucket access to this canonical user id.
{"CanonicalUser":"1234567777777777777777544444444466666ac73d5bc7cd43619"},
        'Action': ['s3:ListBucket'],
        'Resource': f'arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}',
    }]
}
# Convert the policy from JSON dict to string
bucket_policy = json.dumps(bucket_policy)
s3_client.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=bucket_policy)
s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key="a/b/c/abc.txt")
#Still i am getting response for this list_objects operation.
response = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name) 
print(response)
```

How can I remove a specific s3 bucket permission to a root user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments, the question was to deny `root` user access to resources within the same account, which is not recommended as well.

> You can only use an AWS Organizations service control policy (SCP) to limit the permissions of the root user

Below approach described is for cross account access.

As per the documentation you can address root user in the following format

```
"Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::AccountNumber-WithoutHyphens:root"}
```

```
"Principal":{"AWS":["arn:aws:iam::AccountNumber1-WithoutHyphens:root","arn:aws:iam::AccountNumber2-WithoutHyphens:root"]}
```

[Grant permissions to an AWS Account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html)

For example

```json
{
  "Id": "Policy1616693279544",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt161669321",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you don want to stress about correct policy generation you can cross verify with this tool here

[AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)

[Your AWS account identifiers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html#FindingCanonicalId)

Comment: yeah i am doing the same. but instead for accout number i am using canonical user id.

Comment: @learner `CanonicalUser` user id is under the hood converted to aws account number.
`<When you use a canonical user ID in a policy, Amazon S3 might change the canonical ID to the corresponding AWS account ID. This does not impact the policy because both of these IDs identify the same account.>`

Comment: yeah you are correct. yes, it automatically converted canonical id to my aws account number. So you want to use account number instead of canonical id ?

Comment: @learner if you wanna use for root user you have go as described above in the `Principal` section

Comment: I tried changing canonical to root user in principal section but still i am getting response. even i unchecked all `acls`  from s3 console. but no luck

Comment: @learner I tested the above policy if I want to deny a certain account the permissions, above policy works. Plus default action is deny.

Comment: ok. have you created the bucket with the same account ?

Comment: @learner Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230381/discussion-between-samtoddler-and-learner).